# UNIX Input password automatically in shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I have a shell script which has username and password as input.  When I run this script I want these two details to be populated automatically.

How can I do that?

I tried using `expect` but it's not available in my current UNIX version.

Comment: I assume you meant 'expect' rather than 'except', and I edited the question appropriately.  We don't know what you "current UNIX version" is - Linux? HP/UX? AIX? Solaris?  Please [edit] your question to add the appropriate tag, and you'll be much more likely to get good answers.

Comment: You can easily build `expect` (and Tcl/Tk, on which it is built) for any system you're likely to be running (and good few you aren't likely to be running).

Answer (score 1):

Some programs that want you to input a password don't read from stdin, but others do: try just piping them in:

```
{ echo "name"; echo "password"; } | script
```

or

```
script <<'END'
name
password
END
```